# Как отправить POST запрос и спарсить ответ на php?

Tags: php, ajax, post, curl, dom

Пишу парсер отзывов с Яндекс карт, но не могу разобраться как отправить запрос и получить все отзывы.

вот таким кодом я тяну последние 10 отзывов:

```
    <? 

require_once 'parse/simple_html_dom.php';




$ch = curl_init('https://yandex.ru/maps/org/mriya_resort_spa/1303073708/');
// Задаем параметры для курла
$headers = array('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
// Получаем html
$result = curl_exec($ch);
// закрываем курл
curl_close($ch);

$html = str_get_html($result);

foreach($html->find('div.review') as $review) {
    $item['username']     = $review->find('div.review__author div.review__user-name', 0)->plaintext;
    $item['description']    = $review->find('div.review__description', 0)->plaintext;
    $item['date'] = $review->find('meta[itemprop=datePublished]', 0)->content;


    echo $item['username'];
    echo $item['description'];
    echo $item['date'];


}
```

что бы вытащить больше отзывов с этой страницы: [Страница места на Яндекс Картах](https://yandex.ru/maps/org/mriya_resort_spa/1303073708/)

необходимо нажать кнопку "показать больше отзывов", которая имеет такой код:

```
    <div class="reviews__need-more">
    <button class="button button_theme_islands button_size_xl button__control i-bem button_js_inited" role="button" type="button" data-bem="{&quot;button&quot;:{}}">
        <span class="button__text">Показать больше отзывов</span>
    </button> 
</div>
```

В ajax запросы подгружаются через POST:

```
url: https://yandex.ru/maps/org/api/review/get
data: {"oid":"1303073708","page":2,"csrfToken":"****"}
```

Как видим, в json содержится id нужного объекта, номер страницы отзывов, и личный csrfToken, который можно найти в исходном коде страницы. В ответ приходит HTML с комментариями.

вопрос: как и какими методами, может через curl, этот post запрос отправить и получить ответ, что бы в дальнейшем его разобрать на запчасти?

спасибо.

ps.
добавляю в curl следующие строки

```
 $ch = curl_init('https://yandex.ru/maps/org/api/review/get');
    // Задаем параметры для курла
    $headers = array('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
      curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "oid=1303073708&page=2&reqId=1531934712422807-947775942-man1-4890&csrfToken=32df2e0c0f1c36bc02a9f196fcb0b034054a768c:1531934712663");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    // Получаем html
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    // закрываем курл
    curl_close($ch);

    $html = str_get_html($result);
    var_dump($results);
```

но в ответ выдает NULL

Comment: допустимо ли делать несколько curl запросов ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У тебя ошибка в коде, вместо $curl должно быть $ch

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "oid=1303073708&page=2&reqId=1531934712422807-947775942-man1-4890&csrfToken=32df2e0c0f1c36bc02a9f196fcb0b034054a768c:1531934712663");
```

Результат вроде возвращается gzip, потому надо в код добавить

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING , "gzip");
```

Кроме того могут проверятся заголовки типа Referer, User-Agent и т.п., надо смотреть и отпралять их.